# How to show whole database stored records in webpage in php?

Tags: php

**Form.html**

```
<html>
    <head><title>PHP Form</title>
            </head>

    <body bgcolor = "#b3ffff">

        <div>
            <h1 align = "center" border = "5">Dream media solution</h1>
        </div><br>
            <div>
        <form method = "post" action = "welcome.php">

            <table width = "640" align = "center" border = "5" border-color = "red">





            <tr>
                <th>Name:</th>
                <th><input type = "text" name = "uname" placeholder = "Enter ur Name" size="28"></th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Email:</th>
                <th><input type = "email" name = "uemail" placeholder = "Enter ur Email" size="28"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>Password:</th>
                <th><input type = "password" name = "upass" placeholder = "Enter ur Password" size="28"></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>Address:</th>
                <th><textarea size="26" name="address" rows="3" cols="26"></textarea></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>Gender:</th>
                <th><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
                        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male</th>    
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <th>Course:</th>
                        <th><input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="PHP">PHP
                        <input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="Java">Java
                        <input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value=".NET">.NET
                        <input type="checkbox" name="course[]" value="Web Designing">Web Designing</th>
                        </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan = "2" align = "center"><input type = "submit" value  = "login" name = "subname">
                            <input type = "reset" value = "clear"><td>
                    </tr>

            </table>

        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**welcome.php**

```
<body bgcolor = "pink">
<font size = "6" color = "yellow">
    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['subname'])) 
    {
        $counter = 1;
        $name = $_POST['uname'];
        $email = $_POST['uemail'];
        $pass = $_POST['upass'];
        $gender = $_POST['gender'];
         $cou = implode(",", $_POST['course']);

         $address = $_POST['address'];
         //Database connection
        $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "");
        // create databse
        mysqli_query($con, "CREATE DATABASE sms");
        //select database
        mysqli_select_db($con, "sms");

        //Create table
        $ct = "CREATE TABLE student1(sno INTEGER(3) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
        name VARCHAR(20), email VARCHAR(20), password VARCHAR(20), address VARCHAR(50), gender VARCHAR(30), course VARCHAR(30))";
        //Excute table through database
        mysqli_query($con,$ct);
        //Insert records into table through database
        $res = mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO student1 VALUES('', '$name', '$email', '$pass','$address', '$gender', '$cou')");
        echo "<table width = '640' align = 'center' border = '5' bordercolor = 'red' bgcolor='green' cellpadding = '12'>";
        $result  = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student1");
        print_r ($result);
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Sno</th>";
        echo "<th>Name</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>Password</th>";
        echo "<th>Address</th>";
        echo "<th>Gender</th>";
        echo "<th>Course</th>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>".$counter."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$_POST['uname']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$_POST['uemail']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$_POST['upass']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$_POST['address']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$_POST['gender']."</th>";
        echo "<th>".$cou."</th>";

        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</table>";
        if ($res) {
            $msg = "Student Details uploaded successfully";
        }

        else
        {
            $msg = "There is Error in Details please checkout";
        }






            }
    ?>
</font>
```

My database name is sms and table name is student1.

Here i am getting only one record in webpage to show.

But i need over all how many records in database i will loop it and show in webpage, How is it possible please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show all database records please try below code :

```
    echo "<table width = '640' align = 'center' border = '5' bordercolor = 'red' bgcolor='green' cellpadding = '12'>";
    $result  = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM student1");


    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Sno</th>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Email</th>";
    echo "<th>Password</th>";
    echo "<th>Address</th>";
    echo "<th>Gender</th>";
    echo "<th>Course</th>";
    echo "</tr>";

    $i = 1;
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){        
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<th>".$i."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$row['name']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$row['email']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$row['password']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$row['address']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$row['gender']."</th>";
            echo "<th>".$row['course']."</th>";
            echo "</tr>";
    $i++;
    }
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

use while loop { }..

```
  <?php
 $sql=$con,"SELECT * FROM student1";
$i = 1;
 $select = mysql_query($sql);
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($select)){ 

 // Set your Values

 $i++;

    }       ?>
```

OR

refer to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_select.asp)

Answer (score -1):

make changes on your display (form html) page by adding loop or dynamic loop to display the content...     use this code and change according to it..

// Create connection

Comment: if ($conn->connect_error) 
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 

$sql = "SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM MyGuests";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
     // output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) 
         echo "<br> id: ". $row["id"]. " - Name: ". $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"] . "<br>";